# Java SJF Preemptive CPU Scheduling

Tags: java

How can I display the gantt chart using applet of the sjf preemptive scheduling using the following code? How to do the looping to print each process in the applet to generate the gantt chart? And generate an idle rectangle in the gantt chart if the cpu is in idle. I know how to do the gantt chart in paper but I am having a hard time doing it in java.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SRTF {
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("enter no of process:");
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    int pid[] = new int[n]; // it takes pid of process
    int at[] = new int[n]; // at means arrival time
    int bt[] = new int[n]; // bt means burst time
    int ct[] = new int[n]; // ct means complete time
    int ta[] = new int[n];// ta means turn around time
    int wt[] = new int[n];  // wt means waiting time
    int f[] = new int[n];  // f means it is flag it checks process is completed or not
    int k[]= new int[n];   // it is also stores brust time
    int i, st=0, tot=0;
    float avgwt=0, avgta=0;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pid[i]= i+1;
        System.out.println ("enter process " +(i+1)+ " arrival time:");
        at[i]= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter process " +(i+1)+ " burst time:");
        bt[i]= sc.nextInt();
        k[i]= bt[i];
        f[i]= 0;
    }

    while(true){
        int min=99,c=n;
        if (tot==n)
            break;

        for ( i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if ((at[i]<=st) && (f[i]==0) && (bt[i]<min))
            {   
                min=bt[i];
                c=i;
            }
        }

        if (c==n)
            st++;
        else
        {
            bt[c]--;
            st++;
            if (bt[c]==0)
            {
                ct[c]= st;
                f[c]=1;
                tot++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ta[i] = ct[i] - at[i];
        wt[i] = ta[i] - k[i];
        avgwt+= wt[i];
        avgta+= ta[i];
    }

    System.out.println("pid  arrival  burst  complete turn waiting");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pid[i] +"\t"+ at[i]+"\t"+ k[i] +"\t"+ ct[i] +"\t"+ ta[i] +"\t"+ wt[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\naverage tat is "+ (float)(avgta/n));
    System.out.println("average wt is "+ (float)(avgwt/n));
    sc.close();
}
```

}